# Adding canvas dynamically in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, canvas

I'm currently working on an image editor application.
I'm trying to provide the option in my application to work with different layers like in GIMP or Photoshop. My approach is to add a `Canvas` for each layer the user added.
Everything is working pretty nice but somehow my dynamically added canvases don't show up.

In my classes constructor I added 1 general canvas which holds a background-image and which can't be edited. This canvas(which is global) does show up and works properly. All layers that can be edited are stored in a `List<Canvas> canvasLayers`.

This is the method which should add a canvas to my `List` and `Formpanel`.

```
public void addCanvasLayer(String layerName, int id){
    Canvas newCanvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();

    newCanvas.setWidth(this.scaledImageWidth + "px");
    newCanvas.setHeight(this.scaledImageHeight + "px");
    newCanvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(this.scaledImageWidth);
    newCanvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(this.scaledImageHeight);

    newCanvas.getElement().setId(layerName);
    newCanvas.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(id);

    this.fpCanvas.add(newCanvas, new AbsoluteData(0, 0));

    this.canvasLayers.add(newCanvas);
    this.addCanvasHandler(newCanvas);

    context = newCanvas.getContext2d();
}
```

All it does is creating a canvas, setting its size to the main width and height, setting its id and z-index, adding the canvas to my canvaslist, adding handlers to the canvas(clickhandler, onMouseDownHandler,...) and adding the canvas to the main context.

ScaledImageWidth and -Height definitely are NOT null or 0 when adding the canvas.

Any ideas?

Edit: Solved the problem by adding fpCanvas.layout(); to the end of the method.
My formpanel just had to be refreshed <.< ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding fpCanvas.layout(); to the end of the method. My formpanel just had to be refreshed <.< ....

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I manage layers of canvas:

public abstract class Layer
    extends Composite
{

```
/**
 * The canvas used in this layer
 */
private Canvas m_canvas;


public Layer()
{
    m_canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
    initWidget( m_canvas );
}

/**
 * Get the name of the layer (debug purpose only)
 * @return the name of the layer
 */
protected abstract String getLayerName();

/**
 * Set the z-index of the layer
 * @param zindex the new z-index
 */
public void setZ( int zindex )
{
    m_canvas.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex( zindex );
}

public int getZ()
{
    return Integer.parseInt( m_canvas.getElement().getStyle().getZIndex() );
}

@Override
public void setPixelSize( int width, int height )
{
    super.setPixelSize( width, height );
    m_canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth( width );
    m_canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight( height );
}

/**
 * Draw the layer
 */
public void draw()
{
}

/**
 * Get the context2d where this layer will be drawn
 * 
 * @return the Context2d
 */
public final Context2d getContext2d()
{
    return m_canvas.getContext2d();
}

/**
 * Clear the layer
 */
public void clear()
{
    Context2d context2d = getContext2d();
    if ( m_canvas != null && m_canvas.isAttached() )
    {
        context2d.clearRect( 0, 0, m_canvas.getOffsetWidth(), m_canvas.getOffsetHeight() );
    }
}

public LayoutPanel getEnclosingLayoutPanel()
{
    return (LayoutPanel)getParent();
}
```

}

and to add it:

```
    public void addLayer( Layer layer, int zindex )
{
    // m_main is a LayoutPanel
    int width = m_main.getOffsetWidth();
    int height = m_main.getOffsetHeight();
    m_layers.add( layer );
    layer.setZ( zindex );
    if ( m_main.getWidgetCount() > 0 )
    {
        m_main.insert( layer, 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        m_main.add( layer );
    }
    layer.setPixelSize( width, height );
    (...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
I'd unlikely throw my current way to handle my layers so i'll try to figure out what's different:
Instead of handling the canvas itself you have a layer-class which contains a canvas + some functionalities to change properties.
So its only outsourced to a different class.
Could there be a problem with my: Creating a temporary canvas and adding it to my global List<Canvas>?

Comment: The only difference I see is my canvases are the same size as the Widget to which they are attached.

Comment: If you have firefox, open the web developper tools (Ctrl+Shift+i) then open the 3D view. Rotate your page, and check if you can see all your canvas layers on top of each others. When I do that, I can select any layer after descending a few levels donw I finally end up with this: `<canvas style="z-index: 102; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 1227px; height: 426px;" width="1227" height="426" tabindex="0"></canvas>`. Maybe there is something wrong with the size of your canvases.

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution... Here is my status:
My global canvas is attached to my formpanel.
But somehow all canvases created by addCanvasLayer(String layerName, int id) don't show up on the formpanel although I'm using the exactly same code to create my global canvas as in my method. Could it be that it's not possible to create a local canvas, add it to a global List<Canvas> and work with it??
While debugging and watching my formpanel all canvases get attached but my local canvases elementDatas are null.